# I need to use a Hilbert style proof and deduction theorem to solve this, however, I am not allowed to use post theorem.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, computer-science, propositional-calculus

[Picture containing question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pk6Ds.png)

I need help trying to solve this. A short explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I haven't gotten far and that's because I'm not sure at all where to proceed after stating my hypothesis.   1)  A <=> B <=> C   <hyp>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) $A \equiv (B \equiv C)$ --- premise

2) $A$ --- assumed [a]

3) $B \equiv C$ --- from 1) and 2) by [Equanimity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equational_logic) rule.

4) $B$ --- assumed [b]

5) $C$ --- from 3) and 4) by Equanimity.

> 6) $A \to (B \to C)$ --- from 2), 4) and 5) by *Deduction Theorem* twice,  dicarding assumptions [a] and [b],